# Get ID of element being dragged

Tags: jquery, user-interface, draggable

Using the code below, how can I get the id of an element being dragged? And then, if the element ID does not equal 1 then revert element to original position?

Thanks,

```
<script> //DRAG AND DROP EVENTS
    $(".container").delegate(".draggable","mouseenter",function() {
        $(".draggable").draggable({      
            revert : function(event, ui) {
                $(this).data("uiDraggable").originalPosition = {
                    top  : 0,
                    left : 0
                };
                return !event;
            },
            start: function(event,ui) {  // GET ID OF ELEMENT HERE IS NOT WORKING 
              var id = ui.draggable.attr("id");
              console.log(id);
              //GETTING ERROR Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'attr' of undefined
              //IF id <> 1 then revert to original position 
            }
        });

    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
start: function(event, ui) {
   var id = event.target.id;
   console.log(id);
}
```

Comment: Could you please add a bit more explanation..? Where should we add this code? in the revert function..? start callback..?

Answer (score 1):

Inside the function which you pass to the revert option, `this` will refer to the jQuery object corresponding to the element being dragged - You can access it's id using `this.attr("id")`.

Side notes:

- You've initializing the draggable inside an event handler - everytime
  the event is triggered, draggable will be reinitialized... You might
  want to move the initialization out side.
- The [revert](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-revert) callback doesn't have the `event` or `ui` parameters, the only argument it seems to receive is a boolean
- The `ui` parameter inside [`start`](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#event-start) callback doesn't have a draggable property
- It's a good idea to refer the [documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/) instead of making *assumptions*

---

```js
$(".draggable").draggable({
  revert: function (event, ui) {
     return (this.attr("id")==1);
  }
});
```

```css
div {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    line-height:50px;
    margin:5px;
    text-align:center;
    background:red;
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="1" class="draggable">1</div>
<div id="2" class="draggable">2</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but for some reason this does not work for me and I'm thinking it's because I've initialized the draggable inside of an event handler, reason I did that is because this is an ajax calender, and the events are draggable, when I drag once, it doesn't let me drag anymore.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: @DobotJr Your question was, *"how can I get the id of an element being dragged? And then, if the element ID does not equal 1 then revert element to original position?"* - That is answered i believe. Move the initialization to somewhere else where it doesn't happen frequently. You're probably getting errors during the first drag. I added few more things - You are using many things that does not exits. The full code might have many more such things. Open the console and check for errors... Or else ask another question containing the entire code required to reproduce the issue, or a demo...

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it did not work. got a "could not read attr of undefined" or something like that.